# Problems to create webservice jax-ws on WebSphere 8.5

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm using Eclipse Juno to create jax-ws webservice on WebSphere® Application Server V8.5 Tools. The WebService sometimes are created but most often he fails to create wsdl. For example, if i try to create a simple webservice named Web:

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class Web {

    @WebMethod
    public String getName() {
        return "myName";
    }

}
```

After deploying this webservice and viewing WebSphere administration page there is no service named WebService. I tried too access the generated WebSphere wsdl from the url `localhost:9080/MyProject/WebService/WebService.wsdl` but this not exists.

My project have a configured MANIFEST file that contains:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
UseWSFEP61ScanPolicy: true
```

I'm actually using servlet 3.0 but  tried with 2.3. Anyone can help me to do WebSphere approprieate scan annotations of ws-jax and create wsdl on server?

Comment: This code works on WAS 8.5.5.0. Make sure you have declared a package though.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but the package was included in source file =/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution when WebSphere not found WebServices. I modify MANIFESTFILE propertie UseWSFEP61ScanPolicy to false, restart the service and modify angain to true, restart the service and he works.

Comment: When build project the UseWSFEP61ScanPolicy:true disappears.